# Amavis / spamassassin setup, how to disable quarantine and get default spamassassin behavior back?

Tags: spamassassin, amavis

I've set up my first mail server that uses amavis. First off, I don't really see the point in amavis if I don't care about viruses. I don't use clamav as it's a huge RAM hog. SpamAssassin has worked just fine before on its own without amavis.

Just this morning I caught some emails stuck in something called a quarantine (amavis feature). I don't know how to disable the quarantine feature entirely. I'm wondering how to get back the default SpamAssassin behavior where it does nothing more than add `***** SPAM <score> *****` to the subject line, and drops it into my inbox.

Server details: Debian 7.5, postfix 2.9.6, amavisd-new 2.7.1, spamassassin 3.3.2.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on some details?  What specific Server OS/version are you using? What version of SpamAssassin? What version of amavis?

Comment: Details added..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should put this options on your `/etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user` file:

```
$sa_tag_level_deflt  = -999; # add spam info headers if at, or above that level
$sa_tag2_level_deflt = 6.2;  # add 'spam detected' headers at that level
$sa_kill_level_deflt = 6.9;  # triggers spam evasive actions (e.g. blocks mail)
$sa_spam_subject_tag = '**Spam**';
```

Configure the SPAM confidence level to the ones accordingly to your needs.

If you don't want to manage your score levels, you can set the quarantine directories to undefined ones. To do this add those lines in the same file:

```
$clean_quarantine_to      = undef;      # local quarantine
$virus_quarantine_to      = undef;      # traditional local quarantine
$banned_quarantine_to     = undef;      # local quarantine
$bad_header_quarantine_to = undef;      # local quarantine
$spam_quarantine_to       = undef;      # local quarantine
```

If you want to check the information or take a look at additional information here's the Quarantine block on the AMaViS website: http://www.amavis.org/amavisd-new-docs.html#quarantine

Comment: This doesn't turn off quarantine though. I never want quarantine on, I just want the spam messages to get their subject tagged and delivered to the inbox as they normally would.

Comment: On the $sa_kill_level_deflt = 6.9 put a score so high that will never be trigged to put on quarantine. Adjust the tags on the $sa_tag2_level_deflt.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Should `$sa_tag2_level_deflt` match SpamAssassin's `required_score` value?

Comment: I've added more info. Choose the method that will do better for you.

Comment: Thanks! So, does it make sense to always have the `required_score` value in `/etc/spamassassin/local.cf` match the value of `$sa_tag2_level_deflt`? Or is spamassassin's `required_score` value not even relevant? (upon thinking about it more, I think this is the case.. spamassassin is only being used to return a score, not judge whether something is spam or not)

Comment: Yep, the score setting should be done in AMaViS. Spamassassin will on test the messages for you.

Comment: Thank you, your answers are awesome and have been quite helpful!

Answer (score 7):

The best solution I found was simply to put this in `/etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user`:

```
$final_spam_destiny=D_PASS;
$final_virus_destiny=D_PASS;
```

This way bad e-mails are either marked SPAM or INFECTED, but still delivered to the users, without being rejected, blocked nor quarantined.

See [AMAVIS documentation](https://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/amavisd-new-docs.html#actions)

Comment: In particular "for these actions to have any effect, mail must be allowed to be delivered to a recipient;"