# Spamassassin filter based on destination domain

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, zimbra, amavis

I am trying to configure my SpamAssassin (running in combo with amavisd) in order to lower the spam score limit assigned to emails directed to a specific domain (lower required_score only for incoming mail where the `RCPT TO` reads *@example.com).

Is it possible to obtain this behaviour without per-user customization of SpamAssassin for each user belonging to the specific domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Spam Assassin with Amavisd, [then amavisd don't use parameter](https://serverfault.com/questions/613997/amavis-spamassassin-setup-how-to-disable-quarantine-and-get-default-spamassas#comment734011_614004) `required_score` to determine spam score limit. Instead of this, amavis has three level of score here

```
$sa_tag_level_deflt  = 1; # add spam info headers if at, or above that level
$sa_tag2_level_deflt = 6.2;  # add 'spam detected' headers at that level
$sa_kill_level_deflt = 6.9;  # triggers spam evasive actions (e.g. blocks mail)
```

You can tune this score so it match your need. Consults amavisd documentation to know explore those three settings.

---

Now, we focus how we can tune above numbers for particular recipient. Now you can use [maps provided by Amavis](http://www200.pair.com/mecham/spam/bypassing.html#9), see this [amavisd.conf sample](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/amavisd/amavisd-114/amavisd/amavisd-new-2.3.3/amavisd.conf-sample).

```
# advanced example specifying per-recipient values using a hash lookup:
#@spam_tag_level_maps  = (\$sa_tag_level_deflt);  # this is a default
#@spam_tag2_level_maps = (
#  { 'user1@example.com' => 8.0, '.example.com' => 6.0 },
#  \$sa_tag2_level_deflt,   # catchall default
#);
#@spam_kill_level_maps = (
#  { 'user1@example.com' => 8.0, '.example.com' => 6.0 },
#  \$sa_kill_level_deflt,   # catchall default
#);
#@spam_dsn_cutoff_level_maps = (
#  { 'user1@example.com' => 10, '.example.com' => 15 },
#  \$sa_dsn_cutoff_level,   # catchall default
#);
```